# Python Regex Return Number After Space or Hyphen and Exclude Single Digit

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code:

```
text = str('''\
num1 - 1.23
num2-3.21
num3 - 9.31\
''')

re.findall(r'[\d.]+', str([i for i in text.split('\n')]))
```

Please note how *num2* did not have any spaces.

This returns:

> ['1', '1.23', '2', '3.21', '3', '9.31']

However I only want to return a list of the value of each num.

> ['1.23', '3.21', '9.31']

Does anyone know how I can ignore the first digit attached to num and only retrieve the digits after a space or a hyphen?

Comment: Just use: `r'\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?'` OR `r'(?<=[ -])\d+(?:\.\d+)?'`

Answer (score 2):

You can search and learn about [lookahead and lookbehind](https://queirozf.com/entries/python-regular-expressions-lookahead-and-lookbehind-examples) in the context of regular expressions.

> only retrieve the digits after a space or a hyphen?

```
re.findall(r'(?<=[ -])\d+(?:\.\d+)?', text)
```

- `(?<=[ -])` means: *match only if it is preceded by space or hyphen, but do not capture*.
- `\d+` means: *match one or more digits*
- `(?:\.\d+)?` means: *optionally, match if followed by a dot with one or more digits, and capture.*

Answer (score 1):

If you are using re.findall you can use a capture group.

To prevent a partial word match at the end of the digits, you could add a word boundary `\b` if desired.

```
[ -](\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

**Explanation**

- `[ -]` Match either a space or hyphen
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XgZ5yM/1)

```
import re

text = ("num1 - 1.23\nnum2-3.21\nnum3 - 9.31")
print(re.findall(r'[ -](\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', text))
```

Output

```
['1.23', '3.21', '9.31']
```